# Why does Ruby unpack sometimes return an array, but sometimes return values?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, unpack

In the code below I use unpack() to ready some bytes from a string:

```
  # unpack two bytes
  byte1, byte2 = "ABCDEFG".unpack("CC")
  # unpack one byte
  byte3 = "ABCDEFG".unpack("C")
```

When I hover over `byte1` I see `65`, when I hover over `byte2` I see `66`, but when I hover over `byte3` I see `[0] = 65`. Why is this?

Comment: @Yule is vscode, if that matters

Comment: To see what's going on, try `byte1, byte2 = [ 65, 66 ]` and hover over the variables then…

Comment: @Arkku That's essentially what's happening now. The issue is because the second example doesn't destructure the result, so it's just the normally-returned array.

Comment: @Arkku But that doesn't explain anything--OP is asking why they're different, and it's the second example that is confusing the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example you're destructuring the returned array.

In the second example you're not.

`unpack` always returns an array (as described in the docs) but what you *do* with that array will affect what's displayed in your editor/IDE. In the second example you're setting a single value to the return value of `unpack`, the array.